# How to perform data ingestion from hive compressed orc to druid

Tags: hive, druid

I am trying to ingest data into druid from hive orc compressed table data in hdfs. Any pointers on this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Druid and Yarn/MapReduce setup already, you can launch a index_hadoop task that will do what you ask.

There is a druid-orc-extensions that allows to read ORC file, I don't think it come with the standard release, so you'll have to get it somehow (we build it from source)

(extension list http://druid.io/docs/latest/development/extensions.html)

---

Here an example that would ingest a bunch of orc file and append an interval to a datasource. to POST to an overlord http://*overlord*:8090/druid/indexer/v1/task

(doc http://druid.io/docs/latest/ingestion/batch-ingestion.html)

You may have to adjust depending of your distribution, I remember we had issue on hortonworks with some class not found (classpathPrefix will help adjusting MapReduce classpath)

```
{
  "type": "index_hadoop",
  "spec": {
    "ioConfig": {
      "type": "hadoop",
      "inputSpec": {
        "type": "granularity",
        "inputFormat": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcNewInputFormat",
        "dataGranularity": "hour",
        "inputPath": "/apps/hive/warehouse/table1",
        "filePattern": ".*",
        "pathFormat": "'partition='yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH"
      }
    },
    "dataSchema": {
      "dataSource": "cube_indexed_from_orc",
      "parser": {
        "type": "orc",
        "parseSpec": {
          "format": "timeAndDims",
          "timestampSpec": {
            "column": "timestamp",
            "format": "nano"
          },
          "dimensionsSpec": {
            "dimensions": ["cola", "colb", "colc"],
            "dimensionExclusions": [],
            "spatialDimensions": []
          }
        },
        "typeString": "struct<timestamp:bigint,cola:bigint,colb:string,colc:string,cold:bigint>"
      },
      "metricsSpec": [{
        "type": "count",
        "name": "count"
      }],
      "granularitySpec": {
        "type": "uniform",
        "segmentGranularity": "DAY",
        "queryGranularity": "HOUR",
        "intervals": ["2017-06-14T00:00:00.000Z/2017-06-15T00:00:00.000Z"]
      }
    },
    "tuningConfig": {
      "type": "hadoop",
      "partitionsSpec": {
        "type": "hashed",
        "targetPartitionSize": 5000000
      },
      "leaveIntermediate": false,
      "forceExtendableShardSpecs": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your feedback Pierre